# Are accessors necessary in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, oop, encapsulation, accessor

I understand the importance of encapsulation in OOP, and accessors (getters/setters) provide this level of abstraction.

However, with Typescript I can substitute my property with accessors at a later date, with the same name, and rename my property to be prefixed with an underscore (therefore not causing a breaking change).

For example I could have:

```
class foo {

  name: string;

}
```

Later if I wish to add accessors to this property I could change to the following:

```
class foo {

  private _name: string;

  get name():boolean {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
  }

}
```

Is this considered bad practice?

What is the purpose of the accessors in this context?

Comment: Such accessors have no purpose. They would have if they did something other than what a simple public field does (like computing some other property when the setter is called, for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessors are an implementation detail. If you follow "[program to the interface, not to the implementaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)" rule, users of `foo` should only see

```
interface foo {
    name: string;
}
```

How exactly this interface is implemented does not matter. It could be a class with getters and setters, a class with public property, or even a plain object.

Whichever is best is determined by the constraints that particular implementation must obey. In most cases, accessors don't seem to be necessary, but could be convenient sometimes.